# How can I sort the output of a UNION query with different orders for different parts of the UNION?

Tags: mysql

I need the union of 2 queries, but the results must be in a specific order:

1. First must be results from 1 query, sorted by name.
2. Other results must be from 2 query and sorted by date.

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
                 (SELECT c.category_id as media_id,
                        null as media_users_id,
                        c2l.category_name as media_title,
                        null as media_duration,
                        null as media_upload_timestamp,
                        null as media_key,
                        null as media_conversion_info,
                        null as media_type,
                        null as media_views,
                        null as media_embed_views,
                        null as media_comments_count,
                        null as media_accept_ratings,
                        null as media_accept_comments,
                        NOW() as media_upload_date,
                        null as media_ratings_sum,
                        null as media_ratings_count,
                        null as categories2media_category_id,
                        null as categories2media_media_id,
                        1 as type
                      FROM ost_categories c
                      LEFT JOIN ost_categories2language c2l
                      ON c2l.category_id = c.category_id
                      WHERE c2l.category_language = 'russian' AND c.category_parent_id = '60' AND c.is_group = '1'
                      ORDER BY media_title)

                            UNION

                 (SELECT
                          m.media_id,
                          m.media_users_id,
                          m.media_title,
                          m.media_duration,
                      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.media_upload_date) media_upload_timestamp,
                          m.media_key,
                          m.media_conversion_info,
                          m.media_type,
                          m.media_views,
                          m.media_embed_views,
                          m.media_comments_count,
                          m.media_accept_ratings,
                          m.media_accept_comments,
                          m.media_upload_date,
                          m.media_ratings_sum,
                          m.media_ratings_count,
                          c2m.categories2media_category_id,
                          c2m.categories2media_media_id,
                          0 as type
                        FROM ost_media m,
                            ost_categories2media c2m
                        WHERE   c2m.categories2media_category_id = '60'
                          AND c2m.categories2media_media_id = m.media_id
                          AND m.media_type = 'video'
                          AND (m.media_access='public' OR (m.media_access='private' AND m.media_users_id=2))
                          AND m.media_conversion_status = 'success'
                          AND m.media_notified_status = 'legal' ORDER BY m.media_upload_date DESC)
                 ) t LIMIT 0,28
```

But the ordering is wrong. How I can fix this?

Comment: Suggestion: you could omit many (say 10 or more) of the selected column names from your question, which would leave your question more compact and easily understood.  You could leave a comment `-- And other values` or something like that to indicate that the full query is more complex.  Doing this might leave your whole query visible in the question without a scrollbar - that is usually desirable.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` doesn't care how the results of the queries are sorted, you have to specify an order outside of `UNION`.

You have to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
             (SELECT c.category_id as media_id,
                    null as media_users_id,
                    c2l.category_name as media_title,
                    null as media_duration,
                    null as media_upload_timestamp,
                    null as media_key,
                    null as media_conversion_info,
                    null as media_type,
                    null as media_views,
                    null as media_embed_views,
                    null as media_comments_count,
                    null as media_accept_ratings,
                    null as media_accept_comments,
                    NOW() as media_upload_date,
                    null as media_ratings_sum,
                    null as media_ratings_count,
                    null as categories2media_category_id,
                    null as categories2media_media_id,
                    1 as type
                    c2l.category_name AS ordername
                  FROM ost_categories c
                  LEFT JOIN ost_categories2language c2l
                  ON c2l.category_id = c.category_id
                  WHERE c2l.category_language = 'russian' AND c.category_parent_id = '60' AND c.is_group = '1')

                        UNION

             (SELECT
                      m.media_id,
                      m.media_users_id,
                      m.media_title,
                      m.media_duration,
                      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.media_upload_date) media_upload_timestamp,
                      m.media_key,
                      m.media_conversion_info,
                      m.media_type,
                      m.media_views,
                      m.media_embed_views,
                      m.media_comments_count,
                      m.media_accept_ratings,
                      m.media_accept_comments,
                      m.media_upload_date,
                      m.media_ratings_sum,
                      m.media_ratings_count,
                      c2m.categories2media_category_id,
                      c2m.categories2media_media_id,
                      0 as type
                      "" AS ordername
                    FROM ost_media m,
                        ost_categories2media c2m
                    WHERE   c2m.categories2media_category_id = '60'
                      AND c2m.categories2media_media_id = m.media_id
                      AND m.media_type = 'video'
                      AND (m.media_access='public' OR (m.media_access='private' AND m.media_users_id=2))
                      AND m.media_conversion_status = 'success'
                      AND m.media_notified_status = 'legal')
             ) t 
ORDER BY t.type DESC, t.ordername ASC,  t.media_upload_date DESC
LIMIT 0,28
```

Note: I used `type` to sort according to if the row came from query 1 or query 2. I introduced a `ordername` column and set it to "" for query 2 so that it has no effect on the order of those rows.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting inside selects doesn't influence resulted UNION query.
You can only place rows are selected from selects one after the other. 
For example,

```
(select 1 sort_by, .....)
union
(select 2, .....) order by sort_by.
```

Also in this case you can sort rows inside groups loke order by sort_by, media_title but this one will influence order in each result set. 
See more info in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html